# dplyr: summarize data.frame to get the highest and lowest values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame that I want to summarise to get the highest (5 values) and the lowest (5 values) for each column. I used `iris` for a reproducible example.

The highest 5 values for all variables in `iris` can be obtained using

```
df_h <-  iris %>% 
  dplyr::select(Species, everything()) %>% 
  tidyr::gather("id", "value", 2:5) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(Species, id, desc(value)) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Species, id ) %>% 
  top_n(n = 5) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(category = "high")
```

for the lowest 5 values, I used the same except `top_n(n = -5)`.

```
df_l <-  iris %>% 
  dplyr::select(Species, everything()) %>% 
  tidyr::gather("id", "value", 2:5) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(Species, id, desc(value)) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Species, id ) %>% 
  top_n(n = -5) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(category = "low")
```

Then, I joined the two data.frames together df_h (the highest 5 values) and df_l (the lowest 5 values).

```
df_fin <-  df_h %>% bind_rows(., df_l)
```

I'm looking for an efficient/shorter way to get the same result without having to create two data.frames and join them. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to just extract the extreme values, you can combine the two applications of `top_n` with a compound condition in `filter` (note that `top_n` is just a shortcut to `filter` using `min_rank`):

```
    library(tidyverse)

    iris %>% 
          gather("dims", "value", -Species) %>%
          group_by(Species, dims) %>%
          filter( min_rank(desc(value)) <= 5 | 
                    min_rank(value) <= 5 ) -> df_hi_lo
```

However, this won't include the high/low categorization.

A more flexible solution is to use a function that returns either one of these category names or an empty string:

```
hilo <- function(x, n) {
  hi_rk <- min_rank(desc(x))  # change rank function as needed
  lo_rk <- min_rank(x)
  paste0(ifelse(hi_rk <= n, "high", ""),
                ifelse(lo_rk <= n, "low",""))
```

I used the `min_rank` function here, which duplicates the behavior of `top_n`, but you should also consider replacing it with `dense_rank`.

This allows you to add the category for all rows, then filter to just the high/low values:

```
iris %>% gather("dims", "value", -Species) %>%
  group_by(Species, dims) %>%
  mutate(category = hilo(value, 5) ) %>%
  filter(category != "") -> df_hl
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I think you could use a ranking function to do this task programmatically and in a single data frame.

I pulled together an example using the `iris` dataset (below). Basically, it does three things beyond your initial starting spot:

1. Creates a temporary variable called `rank` which calculates and determines the value's position in its column of values. I used `dense_rank` from dplyr as a proof of concept, but you may want a different ranking function depending on your purpose.
2. Calculates the `high_category_lower_bound`, which is the 5th highest ranked value for the group. It also sets the `low_category_upper_bound`, which is nice for programmatically controlling it, but in this example is hard-coded as 5.
3. Filters the dataframe to include only values less than or equal to the `low_category_upper_bound` or greater than or equal to `high_category_lower_bound`, and then does an `ifelse` lookup to create the category.

*Notes:*

- I also forced `distinct` on each column/value pair. I did this to make the solution simpler. If you want the non-distinct values, you'll potentially need to adapt the ranking function. The dense rank gives them the same rank, so they'd be returned multiple times without making it distinct first.
- I replaced `2:5` with `1:ncol(.)`, but your mileage may vary depending on the exact datasets you're actually using.
- If you cared about the reason(s) why a record was included in the dataset, you could retain some of the temporary columns I creted and then removed from the final results.
- Depending on the scale of the dataset(s) you're actually using, this solution may be more or less effective than you'd like. The downside of this solution is that it has to rank all of the values, which could be potentially expensive on a large-scale dataset. I'm personally a fan of using the solution and seeing if it'll scale to your needs, but it's something to be aware of. On the `iris` dataset it returns really quickly. On a couple million rows, it may take a bit longer.

---

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_all <- 
    iris %>%
    # gather all columns
    gather("column", "value", 1:ncol(.)) %>% 
    # filter to only values which can be evaluated as high/low;
    # you could expand this to include factor variables, but 
    # that's beyond the scope of this question and you'd have to
    # redefine the factor levels before this step
    filter(!is.na(as.numeric(value))) %>%
    # get distinct values - optional but probably helpful
    distinct(column, value) %>%
    # group by and perform set operations on 
    group_by(column) %>%
    # create ranking sequence
    mutate(
        rank = dense_rank(value),
        low_category_upper_bound = 5,
        high_rank = max(rank),
        high_category_lower_bound = high_rank - 4 
    ) %>%
    # retain only top and bottom values
    # filter and create category label
    filter(
        rank <= low_category_upper_bound | 
        rank >= high_category_lower_bound
    ) %>%
    mutate(
        category = ifelse(rank >= high_category_lower_bound, "high", ""),
        category = ifelse(rank <= low_category_upper_bound, "low", category)
    ) %>%
    # select columns of interest
    select(column, value, category)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help